# Как совпадение вывести по его номеру из Regex

Tags: c#

```
page = Regex.Match(page, "/message/(.*?)\"").Groups[1].Value;
```

Так он дает первое совпадение. А как вывести, к примеру, второе или третье
без цикла и `page.NextMatch();`?

Comment: Видимо никак...

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема? `Regex.Match(...).Select(m => m.Value).ToArray()` и берите по индексу нужное

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать функцию `Matches`, которая ищет сразу все совпадения.

```
string pattern = @"\b\w+es\b";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string sentence = string sentence = "Who writes these notes?";
var allMatches = rgx.Matches(sentence);
/* берём первый элемент */
Console.WriteLine(allMatches[1]);
```

тестируем код [тут](https://ideone.com/NmglhQ).

Как я понимаю вы хотите без лишних операций сразу найти второе вхождение, но так не получится, так как алгоритм в любом случае должен найти первое вхождение что бы понять какое второе и так далее.

То есть для нахождение второго и третьего первое в любом случае придётся найти, но вот 4,5,6 уже по своей сути можно не искать. В этом случае можно итерировать через `NextMatch()` до нахождения последнего вхождения которое вам нужно.